# How to fix timer for drawing initiated stopwatch?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hi there I am completing some research for **Alzheimers** - I want to be able to record the time it takes to complete a drawing. Both the time spend with apple pencil on tablet and the time spent overall to complete a drawing (time on tablet plus time in between strokes).

I have created this application so far but can't get the timer to work.

I have the drawing/scribble board down pat.

I have tried many different approaches but I am just not experienced enough in code to work out why it is not starting the timer when the apple pencil hits the tablet. The code below is for the ViewController script.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var canvasView: CanvasView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func clearCanvas(_ sender: Any) {  //this button will clear canvas and clear timers!
    canvasView.clearCanvas()
    timer.invalidate()

    seconds = 0    //Here we manually enter the restarting point for the seconds, but it would be wiser to make this a variable or constant.
    timeDrawing.text = "\(seconds)"
}
@IBOutlet weak var timeDrawing: UILabel! //This is one of the label used to display the time drawing (i have yet to add the label to display the time inbetween strokes)

var seconds = 0 
var timer = Timer()
var isTimerRunning = false //This will be used to make sure only one timer is created at a time.
var resumeTapped = false
var touchPoint:CGPoint!
var touches:UITouch!

func runTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,   selector: (#selector(ViewController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func updateTimer() {
        seconds += 1     
    timeDrawing.text = "\(seconds)" //This will update the label.
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    let touches = touch.location(in: canvasView) // or maybe ...(in: self)

    if touch.type == .pencil  {
       if !isTimerRunning {
            runTimer()
        } else {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
}
}
}
```

I was hoping when the apple pencil touched the tablet it would start the timer. And then when the pencil left the tablet it would stop one of the timers. (i have yet to add another timer for the time inbetween strokes, any help with that would be appreciated too.)

Comment: Subclass `UIView`.  And use `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` in it.

Comment: Thank El Tomato, I did what Rita and you instructed but I get the error: Nil cannot be assigned to type 'Timer', If i remove that line it still won't count up. what should I do next? The drawing required for the test should only take seconds

Answer (score 0):

As @ElTomato said you're looking for `touchesEnded`.

You have to move `timer.invalidate()` from `touchesBegan` to `touchesEnded`.
Also you should change your `updateTimer` logic for more high accuracy.

```
private(set) var from: Date?

@objc func updateTimer() {
    let to = Date()
    let timeIntervalFrom = (from ?? to).timeIntervalSince1970
    let time = to.timeIntervalSince1970 - timeIntervalFrom
    timeDrawing.text = "\(round(time))" //This will update the label.
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    let touches = touch.location(in: canvasView) // or maybe ...(in: self)

    if touch.type == .pencil  {
       if !isTimerRunning {
           from = Date()
           runTimer()
       }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    if !isTimerRunning {
        timer.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        from = nil
        timeDrawing.text = "0"
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get the error: Nil cannot be assigned to type 'Timer'. THanks so much Rita, for your help. If i block out that line the time still won't count up. any other thoughts? thanks so much again, I hope this app will help many people with the results I get.

Comment: The drawing should only take seconds

Comment: @RichardBuckley sorry for mistake. You might make  `timer` variable optional. `var timer: Timer?`. By calculating the difference between **date from** and **date to**, you will get the difference in seconds.

Comment: @RichardBuckley if you're looking for more complex timer logic (like start/pause/stop) you can check the article http://www.popcornomnom.com/create-a-stopwatchcountdown-for-ios-using-swift-5/

Comment: Thanks for the further advice, Rita unfortunately the timer is still not updating. anyy other options? I installed the code exactly as you indicated.

Comment: The thing is Rita, is that I need it to be logged with the drawing of the apple pencil (when it touches the tablet and draws the image) and then the timer needs to stop when the pencil comes off the tablet. I haven't found a tutorial that can explain it as yet. But thanks for the link. I found a similar one and i had based the original code of that to no avail. Thanks again.

Comment: @RichardBuckley Do you have any other places where `isTimerRunning` may change?

Comment: Not too sure what you mean Rita, how do I set it to true, so that it will run if it isn't. This is the main file, The other file's don't have other places affecting isTimerRunning.

Comment: Maybe you can share all your code? for completeness

Comment: @RichardBuckley I created simple project for you https://github.com/popcornomnom/DrawingWithTimer. Hope this helps

Comment: God bless, will try in the morning. Thanks so much Rita

Comment: Rita in the application the stopwatch resets after each stroke stops, I need it to keep adding the time together for each stroke.

Comment: @RichardBuckley For this purpose you can do `timer.toggle ()` instead of `timer.stop ()`, this will pause the timer and resume when you start drawing again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works for the code below.  1. Drag a `UIView` control from the object library onto the storyboard.  While this control is selected, enter 'TouchView' in the class field under the identity inspector.  Make an IBOutlet connection to the view controller, naming it touchView.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, TouchViewDelegate {
    // MARK: - Variables

    // MARK: - IBOutlet
    @IBOutlet weak var touchView: TouchView!

    // MARK: - IBAction

    // MARK: - Life cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        /* delegate */
        touchView.touchViewDelegate = self
    }

    // MARK: - Protocol
    var startDate: Date?
    func touchBegan(date: Date) {
        startDate = date
    }

    func touchEnd(date: Date) {
        if let myDate = startDate {
            let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: myDate, to: date)
            if let secs = components.second {
                print(secs)
            }
        }
    }
}

import UIKit

protocol TouchViewDelegate: class {
    func touchBegan(date: Date)
    func touchEnd(date: Date)
}

class TouchView: UIView {
    weak var touchViewDelegate: TouchViewDelegate?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = event?.allTouches?.first
        if let touchPoint = touch?.location(in: self) {
            if self.bounds.contains(touchPoint) {
                Swift.print("You have started a session")
                touchViewDelegate?.touchBegan(date: Date())
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        Swift.print("You have ended the session.")
        touchViewDelegate?.touchEnd(date: Date())
    }
}
```

So when the user touches the touch view, `TouchView` will make a delegate call to the view controller.  When the user gets his finger off off the touch view, it will make another call to the view controller.  And the view controller will calculate the difference between two dates.  So you don't need a timer.  It's my person opinion, but you should stay away from `Timer` unless you have no alternatives.